# Sharepoint RUP OOAD Diagrams

Tags: sharepoint, model, ooad, rup

I work on project which using Sharepoint as platform and we should give RUP Design model,design class and design package to employer. But there is no Design model or other OOAD diagrams for Sharepoint (especially Sharepoint 2013) or I can't find that.

Is there any RUP OOAD diagrams for sharepoint?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found some SharePoint UML diagrams around definition, features, provisioning etc... here: http://technocktail.info/?p=19

Maybe they help you in modelling these parts of the solution.